# jqgrid width/height of jqGrid add/edit panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

how can I set the width and height of edit/add panel that appear if I click on add record button of jqGrid?

```
jQuery("#tabImprese").jqGrid({...}).navGrid('#pagerImprese',
    {

        }, //options
        {   
        }
        }, // edit options
        {
            reloadAfterSubmit:false
        }, // add options
        {
            reloadAfterSubmit:true
        }, // del options
        {
            reloadAfterSubmit:true
        } // search options
        );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use the corresponding properties `width` and `height` described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties), [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties2) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options). Mostly you need use only `width` property (like `width:500`).